# Update an individual record in CoreData

Tags: core-data, ios6

I have  the following situation:

Data is read from a `CoreData` entity into an array called observationList

Looping through the array the data is checked and it may be that the data at position x needs to be updated.

```
for (int x = 0; x < [observationList count]; x++)
{
  //check for need of data update - if there is a need to update ....

  for (NSManagedObject *schoolObject in [self observationList])
  {
  [schoolObject setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", classCheck] forKey:@"obsClassName"];
  }

  NSError *error;
  [context save:&error];
}
```

I realise that what I am doing is updating all the records in CoreData and so what I am asking is how to specifically update the record at position x.

Comment: Your loop is not incrementing anything, is this a typo?

Comment: You won't be saving every object, only those objects which have changes.

Comment: @Abizern I a not sure I agree - the for (NSManagedObject *schoolObject in [self observationList]) line means I go through all of the list but what I want to do is just target the record at position x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `schoolObject` is in `observationList`, then you have to update only specific record at position x is

```
for (int x = 0; x < [observationList count]; x++)
{
  NSManagedObject *schoolObject = [[self observationList] objectAtIndex:x];

   //check for need of data update - if there is condition

  [schoolObject setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", classCheck] forKey:@"obsClassName"];

  NSError *error;
  [context save:&error];
}
```

first fetch `schoolObject` from `observationList` with the specific position and update with proper conditions

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?
After your check, get the object like this:

```
NSManagedObject *schoolObject = [[self observationList] objectAtIndex:x]
```

Then set the value as you want.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't appear to.